# State Machine Class cast exception

Tags: spring-statemachine

Hello again about Spring statemachines. :)
I have a scenario where I have to store an object in the extended state of the state machine and get it later on for processing purposes. As the request enters the SM I do the following and put the object into the extended state.

```
SIMAccountInfo accountInfo =message.getHeaders().get("accountInfo");
stateMachine.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("acc", accountInfo);
```

Then i persist the state machine in redis and later on when I need this object for processing I get it as below

```
            SIMAccountInfo simAccountInfo =(SIMAccountInfo) context.getStateMachine().getExtendedState().getVariables().get("acc");
```

But I get a class cast exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ctf.sims.dto.xboss.SIMAccountInfo
>   cannot be cast to com.ctf.sims.dto.xboss.SIMAccountInfo

Can you guess why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Might be something to do with kryo serialisation we use with redis as I don't remember adding anything with custom classes in extended state.

You may want to create a new GH issue for this with enough information to reproduce a it.